# How to create a buffer along a curve in Rhinoceros 5?

Tags: autocad

Say I have a line `(0,0)<--->(1,0)` and I want to make a rounded "buffer" along it (or any curve, just keeping it simple) in such a way that I now have a closed curve with radius 0.5 so that I end up with a rectangle with semi-circles on each end that is 1 unit in height, and 2 units in width.

Comment: Is "Buffer" == "Slot"?

Comment: Can you sketch what you want on paper? It would help to get a better idea of what you're trying to accomplish